# Hibernate with SQL server 2014

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi i am new to Hibernate. I am using SQL Server 2014 and getting below error :

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

**My `hibernate.cgf.xml` :**

[image: Configuration file]

**Jars that I have included :**

[image: Included jars]

Please help me fix that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the error is on the propertyname? Try:

`<property name="hibernate.dialect">` instead of `<property name="dialect">`

or maybe

`<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>`

Let me know if it works.

(Have you tried removing the dialect line? see what happens..)